# Custom TableViewCell conflicting with newly associated .xib cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have implemented "Clear" app style swipes for deleting and archiving articles (SHCTableViewCell). It worked well. Now I wanted to have some more labels on my cell and I have created custom table view cell form xib file. Then, I associated it with class of my custom cell(which uses swipes). I gave an identifier to xib cell.

and added in my cellForRowAtIndexPath this code:

```
if (!cell)
    {
        [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"SHCTableViewCell_inbox" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
```

Well, nice! Now I can see my my custom labels, but swipes do not work.
What could have caused this conflict?

InboxViewController.m

```
. . . 

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ContentCell";

    SHCTableViewCell_inbox *cell = nil;//[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (!cell)
    {
        [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"SHCTableViewCell_inbox" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    Article* article = [self.articles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.blog.text = article.blog;
    cell.rating.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%ld", (long)article.rating];
    cell.title.text = article.title;
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

    cell.delegate = self;
    cell.todoItem = article;
    return cell;
}

. . .
```

xib cell file:

[image]

EDIT:
I think that it is something to do with gesture recogniser. SHCTableViewCell_inbox has  initWithStyle: and apparently, it never gets called.
Next lines of code are in initWithStyle, that are responsible for gesture recognition.
    UIGestureRecognizer* recognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
            recognizer.delegate = self;
            [self addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];

Comment: Probably it does not relates to the problem but you should consider moving `[tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"SHCTableViewCell_inbox" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];` to `viewDidLoad`. And you should not check cell for `nil`, just call `cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];`. Do not forget `... forIndexPath:` you code miss it.

Comment: Hi, thank you. I made those changes.

Comment: What do you mean by "Custom TableViewCell conflicting with newly associated .xib cell"? Do you receive any errors? Or app just stopped to response to swipe gesture?

Comment: Yeah, It just does not recognise swipes that before used to work. Swipes just don't happen. I can only click on the cell.

Comment: Only thing I did, is added a few IBOutlet labels and associate the xib cell with SHCTableViewCell_inbox class. It does what it supposed to, it shows new labels, but swipe capability is gone.

Comment: How does SwipeGestureRecognizer get initialized? Storyboard, Xib or code? Can you share some screenshots or code describing how gesture recognizer connected with your cell?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57352/discussion-between-user3697016-and-keenle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we figured out in chat: code that has been initializing your cell in times when it was in the storyboard resides in `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` method. After refactoring to Xib you should move that code to `awakeFromNib` method because `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` does not get called.

So you should add code bellow to `SHCTableViewCell_inbox` class:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    UIGestureRecognizer* recognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
    recognizer.delegate = self;
    [self addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];

    // any other code that was in initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:
}
```